# Creating a Rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looking at using the Gibbon gem for Mailchimp integration and I would like to add my API details in `config/initializers/gibbon.rb`

The gem takes in a few things: API KEY, timeout, etc..

I wanted to know the best way to extract this from my controller to an initalizer.

```
# config/initializer/gibbon.rb

Gibbon.api_key = "my-api-key"
Gibbon.timeout = 15
Gibbon.throws_expection = false
```

The above fails with an error: `gibbon.rb:38:in 'merge': can't convert false into Hash (TypeError)`

I wanted to know what is the best practise for this in Rails 3.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo.

It's

```
 Gibbon.throws_exceptions = false
```

Not what you've got. exceptions, not expection.

Comment: Glad to help. We've all been there!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question at all, but try something like:

```
# config/initializer/gibbon.rb
module Gibbon
     Gibbon.api_key = "my-api-key"
     Gibbon.timeout = 15
     Gibbon.throws_expection = false
end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Fernando, I appreciate it. I have issues using the gem because when I enter the api details and options as an initializer it fails. Unfortunately, using a module Gibbon fails also.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Well, look at the error you're getting:</s>

```
gibbon.rb:38:in 'merge': can't convert false into Hash (TypeError)
```

So, what's on line 38 of your initializer? You're only showing us a few lines. It looks like on line 38 you're passing `false` to an argument that is expecting a hash.

If you have the three lines from your question, and only those three lines, saved in `config/initializers/gibbon.rb` it should do what you're expecting.

If you want to paste your whole initializer file into your question I'll come back and check again, and will add to this answer if there's something visibly wrong.

As Edward pointed out, you've just got a typo :)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for taking the time to check out my problem. Sorry, the line the error refers to is the Gem. Setting up a simple Gibbon.api_key = "my-api-key" without any other arguements eg. Gibbon.timeout = 15 works. But when I start adding on settings to the config/initalizer/gibbon.rb is where I'm having problems. I think it requires a hash?

Comment: Typo, see Edward's answer.